# What is R squared for a neural network and what does it signify?

Tags: python, neural-network

I calculated R square for my neural network based on a formula I found somewhere, which goes something like:

[image]

It should be something around 0.98-0.99. But, when I operate it on my network, it yields very low values, sometimes even negative. What can be the reason for this? What does R square signify?

Comment: This question probably belongs better on [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll post there. Could you help me if you know what the problem is?

Comment: Sorry, no, I'm not very familiar with pyBrain.

Comment: Oh, okay. Well, actually, it isn't a python problem. It's a neural network problem. There's this term R squared, it's validation related.

Comment: It's called [the coefficient of determination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_squared).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't a programming question.